# Unable to configure amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Just downloaded amply and did `amplify configure`. It asked me to create an account, gave it administrative access and then asked me to fill in `secretKey` and `secretAccessKey`. I did all. I also named this profile as `serverlesstutorial`

Now i am creating a `react` project and i ran command `amplify init`. Again, it started a wizard and when it asked me to chose the profile, i chose `serverlesstutorial`. And then i got following error

```
init failed
UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
    at Object.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:55:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12) {
  message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.',
  code: 'UnrecognizedClientException',
  time: 2020-11-04T04:42:21.422Z,
  requestId: '5c1663f4-7b60-4c29-8a4d-bbc9b19b3392',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 0.2105412643671034
}
```

This looks like that it is getting bad credentials? So i did `export AWS_PROFILE=serverlesstutorial` just to make sure it picks up correct profile but got the same error

I then checked which profile is current select. So i did `aws configure list` and it showed me that my current profile is `serverlesstutorial`. To verify this, I did this command `aws s3 ls` and it gave me following error

```
❯ aws s3 ls

An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

The next command that i tried is

```
❯ aws s3 ls --profile serverlesstutorial

An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I have tried re-configuring the access key etc, but still getting same error. Any help

Comment: No response for almost 5 days. bumping.

Comment: Getting the same error. did you find any solution ?

Comment: It's pretty old so i don't remember the exact solution but it was related to the credentials not being set properly in `~/aws/config` & `~/aws/credentials`. I used `verbose` flag with `aws cli` to narrow down the issue. And realized that given that my `config` file had mulitple `profiles` it was pointing to the wrong one. The solution should be exposing `AWS_PROFILE` user OR using only one credentials in `credentials` file.